# Storage access via reinterpret_cast and std::launder

Tags: c++, c++17, language-lawyer

I created a memory pool in order to use it as placement new for objects and I use the free slots to have a free-list in order to reuse the slots:

```
template<class T>
class ObjectPool {
public:
    ObjectPool( std::size_t cap );
    virtual ~ObjectPool();
    void* allocate() noexcept(false);
    void deallocate( void* ptr );
private:
    template<typename M>
    static constexpr const M& max( const M& a, const M& b ) {
        return a < b ? b : a;
    }
    using storage = typename std::aligned_storage<max(sizeof(T), sizeof(T*)), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type;
    storage* pool;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::size_t capacity;
    std::size_t counter;
    T* deletedItem;
};

template<class T>
ObjectPool<T>::ObjectPool( std::size_t cap ) :
        capacity(cap), counter(0), deletedItem(nullptr) {
    if ( capacity > 0 )
        pool = ::new storage[cap];
    else
        pool = nullptr;
}

template<class T>
ObjectPool<T>::~ObjectPool() {
    ::delete[] pool;
}

template<class T>
void* ObjectPool<T>::allocate() noexcept(false) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
    if ( deletedItem ) {
        T* result = deletedItem;
        deletedItem = *(reinterpret_cast<T**>(deletedItem)); //<-----undefined behavior??
        return result;
    }

    if ( counter >= capacity ) {
        throw std::bad_alloc();
    }

    return std::addressof(pool[counter++]);
}

template<class T>
void ObjectPool<T>::deallocate( void* ptr ) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
    *(reinterpret_cast<T**>(ptr)) = deletedItem;  //<-----undefined behavior??
    deletedItem = static_cast<T*>(ptr);
}
```

I'm trying to understand if this class has an undefined behavior under C++17 standard. Is it needed to use `std::launder`? From my understanding it isn't since only void pointers and `T` pointers are involved. In addition when in the `deallocate` the object has already been destroyed, so it should be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code exhibits UB under *every* C++ standard, even C++20 which allows (under certain circumstances) implicit object creation. But not for reasons having to do with `launder`.

You can't just take a piece of memory, pretend there's a `T*` there, and treat it like one exists. Yes, even for fundamental types like pointers. You have to *create* objects before you use them. So if you have a disused piece of memory, and you want to shove a `T*` into it, you need to create one with placement-new.

So let's rewrite your code (note that this compiles, but is otherwise untested; the main point is that you must create the elements of your linked list):

```
template<class T>
class ObjectPool {
public:
    ObjectPool( std::size_t cap );
    virtual ~ObjectPool();
    void* allocate() noexcept(false);
    void deallocate( void* ptr );
private:

    using empty_data = void*; //The data stored by an empty block. Does not point to a `T`.
    using empty_ptr = empty_data*; //A pointer to an empty block.

    static constexpr size_t entry_size = std::max(sizeof(T), sizeof(empty_data));
    static constexpr std::align_val_t entry_align =
      std::align_val_t(std::max(alignof(T), alignof(empty_data))); //Ensure proper alignment

    void* pool;
    std::mutex mutex;
    std::size_t capacity;
    //std::size_t counter;  //We don't need a counter; the pool is empty if `freeItem` is NULL
    empty_ptr freeItem; //Points to the first free item.
};

template<class T>
ObjectPool<T>::ObjectPool( std::size_t cap ) :
    pool(::operator new(entry_size * cap, entry_align)),
    capacity(cap)
{
    //Build linked-list of free items, from back to front.
    empty_data previous = nullptr; //Last entry points to nothing.
    std::byte *byte_pool = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(pool); //Indexable pointer into memory
    auto curr_ptr = &byte_pool[entry_size * capacity]; //Pointer to past-the-end element.
    do
    {
        curr_ptr -= entry_size;

        //Must *create* an `empty_data` in the storage.
        empty_ptr curr = new(curr_ptr) empty_data(previous);
        previous = empty_data(curr); //`previous` now points to the newly-created `empty_data`.
    }
    while(curr_ptr != byte_pool);

    freeItem = empty_ptr(previous);
}

template<class T>
ObjectPool<T>::~ObjectPool()
{
    ::operator delete(pool, entry_size * capacity, entry_align);
}

template<class T>
void* ObjectPool<T>::allocate() noexcept(false) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);
    if(!freeItem) { throw std::bad_alloc(); } //No free item means capacity full.

    auto allocated = freeItem;
    freeItem = empty_ptr(*freeItem); //Next entry in linked list is free or nullptr.
    return allocated;
}

template<class T>
void ObjectPool<T>::deallocate( void* ptr ) {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mutex);

    //Must *create* an `empty_data` in the storage. It points to the current free item.
    auto newFree = new(ptr) empty_data(freeItem);
    freeItem = newFree;
}
```

Comment: It depends on what interpretation you choose. Part of the std says that any region sufficiently aligned holds all objects that fit there. Also, it's the only way to use unions. Other interpretations make unions UB.